# Vbscript Website Content, SelectAll Copy and Past into a Notepad *Help*

Tags: vbscript

I got the code to copy the contents of a website into notepad:

```
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "https://example.com"
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
        Wscript.Sleep 100
    Loop
    For Each Tag In .Document.GetElementsByTagName("script")
        Tag.OuterHtml = ""
    Next
    For Each Tag In .Document.GetElementsByTagName("noscript")
        Tag.OuterHtml = ""
    Next
    Content = .Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0).InnerText
    Do While InStr(Content, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
        Content = Replace(Content, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
    Loop
    ShowInNotepad Content
    .Quit
End With

Sub ShowInNotepad(Content)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        TempPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") & "\" & .GetTempName
        With .CreateTextFile(TempPath, True, True)
            .WriteLine (Content)
            .Close
        End With
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "notepad.exe " & TempPath, 1, True
        .DeleteFile (TempPath)
    End With
End Sub
```

I am stuck with above script to save the text as file.txt.

Please help.

Comment: Your code is already saving to a textfile ( and then deleting the file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
Option Explicit
Dim LogFile,Ws,Tag,Content
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "https://example.com"
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
        Wscript.Sleep 100
    Loop
    For Each Tag In .Document.GetElementsByTagName("script")
        Tag.OuterHtml = ""
    Next
    For Each Tag In .Document.GetElementsByTagName("noscript")
        Tag.OuterHtml = ""
    Next
    Content = .Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0).InnerText
    Do While InStr(Content, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
        Content = Replace(Content, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
    Loop
    WriteLog Content,LogFile
    .Quit
End With
Ws.Run LogFile
'*******************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fso,ts 
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForWriting,True,-1)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'******************************************************************
```

Comment: In this case you should mark this answer as "accepted".
Take a look at this ==>  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Just Asking: Is there a way to avoid the text file to open ?

Comment: @PankajKumar Just comment or delete this line : Ws.Run LogFile